# react-redux areStatesEqual is not firing

Tags: react-redux

I am working on a project with react-redux and trying to use the following code:

```
const JsonEditorCont = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null,
    mergeProps,
    {
        areStatesEqual: (next, prev) => {

            console.log(next, prev);

            return (
                false === true
            );
        }

    }
)(JsonEditorComp);
```

My mapStateToProps method is working good.
but areStatesEqual method is not firing at any time, even when mergeProps function is launched after mapStateToProps .
i dont see anything on the log.
and there is not too mutch information about it in the documentation.